# How to inject a ephemeral container into a running Pod having mountable volumes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Pod having a container which has a mounted
This is the deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ubuntu
          image: ubuntu
          command: ["/bin/sleep", "3650d"]
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /diag
              name: diagvol
      volumes:
        - name: diagvol
          emptyDir: {}
```

I want to add a ephemeral container to this pod which can mount the same volume. As my custom debugging tool needs to have a shared dir with the process to communicate to it. How can I create a ephemeral container with this volume mounted on it.

I have tried using the man pages of `kubectl debug` but it has no option to mount the volume, also i can't patch or edit the deployment to mount as it gives forbidden to patch pod.ephemeralcontainer resource

Comment: Can you just `kubectl exec` into the existing container?

Comment: @larsks, the existing container doesn't have a shell, and i need a shell to debug

Comment: Are you looking to inject an container into a pod, then using mutatingwebhook you can inject an container following link has information https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#webhook-configuration

Comment: I don't think there's any way to "inject" a container into a running pod. The mutating webhook solution that @NatarajMedayhal mentions transform the pod manifest *when you submit it*, but will not modify a pod that is already running. I think the easiest solution would be to add a debug container to your pod manifest so that it's available when you need it, or use a pv instead of an emptyDir volume so that it can be accessed from another pod.

Comment: @larsks I can't add another container to the pod manifest itself, but i found a way my problem could be solved https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/ephemeral-containers/, but the only problem with this approach is that "kubectl debug" command has no mount volume option, However the reference docs https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.27/#ephemeralcontainer-v1-core Do mention a volume attribute, I just need a way to use this api

Comment: I have the same problem as you. I'm using distroless images, and I want a way to access the filesystem of a running container without having to recreate an image with this special `debug` tag.

Comment: @Ludal I found a solution but it is more of a workaround, basicly: you'll need to send a PUT request to `/api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{name}/ephemeralcontainers`  api endpoint with the updated manifest containing a spec for ephemeral container with the mounted volume info, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.27/#ephemeralcontainer-v1-core for the format of PUT request